# Solidity Visual Developer

Tags: solidity, visual-studio-code

Can someone let me know for what are those frames around the variables used for and how to turn them off. I assume I added them after installing Solidity Visual Developer plugin for VSC.

[image]

There are also some arrows up as well.

Comment: I think this happens with solhint plugin, if you use solhint, disable it